# How to import AndroidViewBinding in jetpack compose

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, android-viewbinding, xml-layout, composable

I'm trying to use some fragments within jetpack compose but I can not import AndroidViewBinding from (androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop) and it is always appearing as an unresolved name

how to import it ??

Comment: Did you check this link https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/interop/interop-apis#fragments-in-compose ?

Answer (score 16):

I just came against the same problem - unresolved. Turns out, we need to import:

> implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding:$compose_uiversion"

[See here for more info](https://androidx.tech/artifacts/compose.ui/ui-viewbinding/1.3.2) - (latest stable version is 1.3.2)

Just another example where I wish they really made their documentation explicit about dependencies. [This official documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/ui/viewinterop/package-summary) doesn't help.

Comment: Even after adding the dependency the import 
import androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidViewBinding
does not resolve for me.
What is interesting is that in my scenario i can navigate to the  androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop package that is under androidx.compose.ui.ui-android but there is no AndroidViewBinding there. By exploring my dependencies i found that the needed class is under androidx.compose.ui.ui-viewbinding but the import statement does not resolve possibly to a conflict. Anyone had a simiar scenario?