# Failed to resolve: com.github.yogacp:android-viewbinding:1.0.3 Show in Project Structure dialog Affected Modules: app

Tags: android-studio, kotlin

Failed to resolve: com.github.yogacp:android-viewbinding:1.0.3
Show in Project Structure dialog
Affected Modules: app

How to resolved my problem

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't trust that dependency.

Normal [View binding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding) is built-in and can be turned on in your app's `build.gradle` file.

```
android {
    ...
    buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
    }
}
```

There is also `@Composable` [View Binding](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/setup), which can be added with the `implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-viewbinding:1.2.0-beta03"` dependency.  [It isn't initially clear that this dependency is necessary, which is why it is often missed.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74885401/how-to-import-androidviewbinding-in-jetpack-compose)